# How to update a specific record by id in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I would like to update a record by id .

```
functions.updateClassified = function (req, res) {

        loadSchema.findById(req.params.classified_id, function(err, bear) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else
           loadSchema.category = req.body.category;  
           loadSchema.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Classified updated!' });
        });

    });

};
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method :

```
functions.updateClassified = function (req, res) {
    loadSchema.findById(req.params.classified_id, function(err, bear) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else if (bear) {
            bear.category = req.body.category;
            bear.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.json({message: 'Classified updated!'});
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.json({message:'No bear found'});
        }
    });
};
```

Or this one :

```
functions.updateClassified = function (req, res) {
    loadSchema.update({_id:req.params.classified_id}, {$set:{
        category:req.body.category
    }}, function(err, bear) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json({message: 'Classified updated!'});
        }
    });
};
```

Hope it helps :)